# Does iOS ranging AltBeacons?

Tags: ios, xamarin, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm working on app which scan iBeacon and AltBeacons. 
I'm using Xamarin framework.

And there is question: does iOS ranging AltBeacons?
With iBeacons app monitoring and ranging, but with AltBeacon app catch only RegionEnter, RegionLeft events, but not DidRangeBeacons.

Any suggestions?

Tested on iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3. iBeacon, AltBeacon advertised by Samsung SGS5.

P.S. As I remember one year ago iOS working with AltBeacon. But today I tested on iOS 7.0.4 and ranging not working too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is support for scanning AltBeacon advertisements at all in the Xamarin framework on iOS.

This may not be obvious if you have RadiusNetworks RadBeacon products, which send out both iBeacon and AltBeacon advertisements with the same identifiers.  Perhaps this is what you tested one year ago?

Comment: I tested with Jaalee beacons one year ago. I also see jaalee beacon advertisement in iBeaconDetector app (Android). And this was not iBeacon.

Comment: I believe that Jalee beacons do transmit an iBeacon advertisement.

Comment: I post [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/514zdm98j/b7fd5208/) from iBeaconDetector. And there is no iBeacon advertisement.

Comment: It could be that the Jalee beacon is not advertising at all, or it is advertising with a UUID not registered on the iOS app making it not detectable.  To know for sure you would need a beacon scanner on a different platform like my Android Beacon Locate, or ScanBeacon for Mac.

Comment: I test app by Locate (from RadiusNetwork) with same advertisement. And it work. RegionEnter, RegionExit, DidRangeBeacons called. Can Apple update CLLocation Framework silently, without updating iOS firmware? It may be answer why DidRangeBeacons not working with Jaalee beacons.

Comment: You tested with Locate on iOS or Android?  What is the UUID of the detected beacon?

Comment: Locate on Android. UUID - ef4444a4-c096-11e4-8dfc-aa07a5b093db.

Comment: Great!  Try configuring that uuid into Locate for iOS.  When you do, does locate for iOS show the beacon?  If so, that means that the Jaalee beacon is transmitting an iBeacon advertisement, as Locate for iOS only picks up iBeacon advertisements.

Comment: Test with Locate on iOS. This advertising iBeacon format with right UUID. Another iOS device ranging this beacon. But question is: Can Apple update CLLocation Framework silently, without updating iOS firmware? Because Jallee advertising non-iBeacon format, and App was ranging this beacon, but now it can't be ranged.

Comment: Yes, Apple often updates CoreLocation in each incremental OS release.